# How do I create an NSView from a nib in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, user-interface

I am trying to use Swift 5.7.2 to create a macOS menu bar application. Ultimately, I have an `NSMenu` filled with a handful of `NSMenuItems` that have submenus with custom views. I have code that creates this menu then use the following to set the view of the submenu item:

```
subMenuItem.view = SubMenuView(frame: NSRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 160.0, height: 37.0))
```

The SubMenuView looks like this:

[image: SubMenuView]

I have tried turning the nib into an `NSView` a handful of different ways but none have worked. This is what I end up getting:

[image: SubMenuView Result]

My code for the SubMenuView.swift file is below:

```
import Cocoa

class SubMenuView: NSView {

    @IBOutlet var parentView: NSView!

    @IBOutlet var label: NSTextField!

    @IBAction func set(_ sender: NSButton) {
    
    }

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

Above, `parentView` is linked to the background of the SubMenuView, `label` is linked to the text input, and `set` is linked to the button. I know that it has something to do with setting the constraints in the `init` function but can't seem to get it to work. What is the best way of going about this?

Comment: The nib files knows about your `SubMenuView` view class, but the view class doesn't know about the NIB. So when you write `SubMenuView(...)`, you're initializing a new empty view. When you load a view from a Nib, the system will initialize a new empty view from your class just like you did, but it will then also set other settings (its text, layer, and whatever else), and add the subviews specified by the nib.